# Unable to redirect from sharepoint event receiver

Tags: redirect, sharepoint-2010, custom-error-pages

I have created an event receiver on the "Task" list.

If the "Due Date" is `null` then the user should be redirected to the custom error page.

Custom error page resides in the SharePoint mapped folder under "Layouts" directory.

The event receiver code is as follows:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    try
    {
        if (properties.AfterProperties["Due Date"] == null)
        {
            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
            properties.RedirectUrl = "_layouts/CustomErrorPage/DueDateErrorPage.aspx";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

The custom error page which is of type "Application Page" having name. "DueDateErrorPage.aspx". The mark up is:

```
<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
ERROR : You cannot create the task without due date
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
Custom Error Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea"     ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" >
Custom Error Page
</asp:Content>
```

Though in IIS, under the _layouts direcory the page is available I am getting this output.

[image]

How should I tackle this error? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I first checked the url in web browser that is:

`/_layouts/CustomErrorPage/DueDateErrorPage.aspx`

It was opening the page that means the page is available but there is something missing in the url only.

So by using the SPUrlUtility class I was able to redirect the page.

The changes I needed to made was:

```
properties.RedirectUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(properties.WebUrl,"/_layouts/CustomErrorPage/DueDateErrorPage.aspx");
```

It's working perfectly..

Answer (score 4):

I think your redirect url is invalid, because it will be relative to the current page, and not the current site or site collection.

You can diagnose this by looking at the dialog frame properties, and check the url.

1. **Method 1 : solve the amgiguity**

   To resolve ambiguity, I suggest you to use the [SPUtility.GetServerRelativeUrlFromPrefixedUrl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getserverrelativeurlfromprefixedurl.aspx).

   This will create a correct url.

   Especially, change your code like this:

   ```
   properties.RedirectUrl = SPUtility.GetServerRelativeUrlFromPrefixedUrl(
       "~site/_layouts/CustomErrorPage/DueDateErrorPage.aspx"
       );
   ```

   This will dynamically resolve `~site` to your current `SPWeb` url. You can also use `~sitecollection` to resolve the site collection.
2. **Method 2: make the field mandatory**

   Why don't you simply make the due date mandatory?
3. **Method 3: use the standard sharepoint error page (not tested I admit)**

   Instead of redirecting to your own page, "Cancel" the event with a custom error message:

   ```
       properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
       properties.ErrorMessage= "Due date is mandatory";
   ```

   Moreover, `CancelWithRedirectUrl` is now obsolete.

*PS: as a side note, you should know that a [SharePoint dedicated Stack Exchange site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) exists.*

Comment: Thank you for your response sir, I am beginner to the SharPoint and practicing.. I made the changes as per your suggestion but now the error is changed. Error is displaying "An event receiver has canceled the request.. @Steve B

Comment: @RiyazKalva: I think the best way to solve your issue is to follow the method 2. If your requirement is to make the due date mandatory, then let SharePoint handle this and mark the field as mandatory directly in the list structure.